# Extract multiple strings from package DDL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scheduling package which calls procedures and adds them to an event log table depending on the day of month. (A better way to do this is likely a separate discussion.) I'd like to query the package and return the day of month and procedure name.

I'm trying to use some REGEXP functionality after pulling the DDL of the package but can't figure it out.

```
SELECT REGEXP...something AS DayOfMonth
     , REGEXP...something AS ProcName
  FROM (
        SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(d.OBJECT_TYPE, d.OBJECT_NAME, 'ME') AS DDL_STR
          FROM DBA_OBJECTS d
         WHERE d.OWNER = 'ME'
           AND d.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
           AND d.OBJECT_NAME = 'TST_SCHED_PKG'
       ) t
;
```

Subquery `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()` returns a CLOB of:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "ME"."TST_SCHED_PKG2" is

  type run_log_cursor_t is ref cursor return run_log%rowtype;

  procedure run_daily (ioc_run_log_cursor in out run_log_cursor_t);


end TST_SCHED_PKG2;

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE BODY "ME"."TST_SCHED_PKG2" is

  procedure run_daily (ioc_run_log_cursor in out run_log_cursor_t) is

    d_run_daily_start_time date;
    d_start date;
    d_end   date;

  begin --run_daily

    d_run_daily_start_time := sysdate;

    --*************************** MONTHLY PROCEDURES HERE ******************************
    case extract (day from d_run_daily_start_time)

      when 1 then

        ABC.PROC1;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('ABC.PROC1',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

        ABC.PROC2;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('ABC.PROC2',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

      when 2 then

        DEF.PROC3;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('DEF.PROC3',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

        GHI.PROC4;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('GHI.PROC4',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

      when 3 then

        XYZ.PKG1.PROC5(trunc(sysdate));
        d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('XYZ.PKG1.PROC5',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

        XYZ.PKG2.PROC6(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1));
        d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('XYZ.PKG2.PROC6',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

  end; --run_daily

end TST_SCHED_PKG2;
```

Example package:

```
create or replace package body TST_SCHED_PKG is

  procedure run_daily (ioc_run_log_cursor in out run_log_cursor_t) is

    d_run_daily_start_time date;
    d_start date;
    d_end   date;

  begin --run_daily

    d_run_daily_start_time := sysdate;

    --*************************** MONTHLY PROCEDURES HERE ******************************
    case extract (day from d_run_daily_start_time)

      when 1 then

        ABC.PROC1;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('ABC.PROC1',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

        ABC.PROC2;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('ABC.PROC2',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

      when 2 then

        DEF.PROC3;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('DEF.PROC3',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

        GHI.PROC4;
             d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('GHI.PROC4',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

      when 3 then

        XYZ.PKG1.PROC5(trunc(sysdate));
        d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('XYZ.PKG1.PROC5',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

        XYZ.PKG2.PROC6(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1));
        d_end := sysdate;    XYZ.add_event_log('XYZ.PKG2.PROC6',d_start, d_end);    d_start := sysdate;

  end; --run_daily

end TST_SCHED_PKG;
```

For example I'd like to return:

```
DayOfMonth ProcName
1          PROC1
1          PROC2
2          PROC3
2          PROC4
3          PKG1.PROC5
3          PKG2.PROC6
```

Comment: Need the sample data of 'DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(d.OBJECT_TYPE, d.OBJECT_NAME, 'ME')'.

Comment: EDIT: Added to the original question.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do that via a query, rather than just by examining the code yourself? If it's possible at all then you'd have to specify the structure so tightly anyway that it seems like a bit of a waste of effort.

Comment: 1. Not all users have access to the package.

2. It seems cleaner to display the scheduled procedures via, say, a table function (which would return procedures from the DDL), and all users could use the function to query what is scheduled.

3. There is a separate table function which returns the completed procedures, so ideally the two could be combined to see what was scheduled and completed for a given day.

I figured there is a way to capture the first number after `CASE` for the `DayOfMonth`, and the procedure name after `add_event_log(` for `ProcName`.